# Любое количество таблиц с любым количеством строк и столбцов

Tags: java

На вход поступают таблицы (в разном количестве), строк и столбцов в них тоже различно. В каком формате данных их сохранять, чтобы я имел возможность обратится к таблице как к элементу массива (то есть важен их порядок с входа), и соответственно имел доступ к их элементам строк/столбцов? Массив с массивами какой то получается, но размерности неизвестны. Надеюсь понятно объяснил.

Comment: 1. Класс таблица(строки, столбцы)
2. Массив экземпляров класса таблица

Comment: Типы столбцов одинаковые или нет?

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov Да, String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй `List` чтобы можно было динамически изменять его размер. Если хотите иметь таблицу как отдельную сущность делайте так

```
List<Table> tables;

class Table {
   List<List<String>> data;
}
List<List<String>> data= new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>()'
List<String> row = new ArrayList<>();
row.add("a");
row.add("b");
row.add("c");
data.add(row);
Table table = new Table(data);
tables.add(table);
```

чтобы получить данные

```
table.get(2).getData().get(3).get(1);
```

либо если не нужно сущность, то так

```
 List<List<List<String>>> tables;
```

А если вы заранее знаете размеры то лучше использовать двумерный массив

Comment: Спасибо большое, выглядит логчино, но что-то не могу допереть как работать с такой конструкцией, помогите пожалуйста. Буду очень благодарен если дополните примером использования (как мне например добавить таблицу; обратится к 3 таблице - 4 строке 2 столбцу).

Comment: а почему не просто двухмерный массив? это же и получается таблица один в один. массив финализирован, инициализируется в конструкторе, где передается размер таблицы и все становится проще, чем две коллекции...

Comment: @Дмитрий Так мой вопрос как раз в том, что кол-во строк и столбцов изначально мне неизвестно. Получается я один раз по данным пробежал, потом создал массив, и пробегаю ещё раз чтобы эти данные в него забить (вопрос в том как этого избежать).

Comment: @WebFR я оновил ответ

Comment: @Web FR тогда создайте класс,инкапсулирующий обычный лист,передавайте в него таблицу. данные читаются построчно из таблицы и записываются в лист.в процессе чтения фиксируется ширина таблицы (например 10), пишется в отдельную переменную класса типа инт. теперь у вас данные в одномерном массиве и вы знаете ширину таблицы.пишите метод для получения,который принимает координаты ячейки. например 2 строка,3 столбец. метод умножает строку (2)на ширину (10)таблицы и прибаляет столбец(3). простейшее действие и вы знаете индекс элемента в листе. быстро дешево и сердито. простая структура, не запутаешься

Comment: @Alex Lysun Ваше решение идеально вписалось, спасибо!